# where to insert SES key, secret, SMTP username, SMTP password in .env file for laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I've followed advice [here](https://tuts.codingo.me/sending-emails-over-queue-with-aws-ses) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758486/laravel-5-1-aws-sdk-proper-credentials-setup-exception-aws-exception-credentia), but I cannot understand where to put the following four things in my `config/mail.php` and `config/services.php` files 
I am using SMTP, not the API to send mail in my laravel app.

What I don't understand now:
Do I need to use only `MAIL_USERNAME`, `MAIL_PASSWORD`, or do I need to use the `SES_SECRET`, `SES_KEY`as well? From SES, I downloaded a file with my smtp username, smtp password. I guess they are to be plugged into the `MAIL_USERNAME`and `MAIL_PASSWORD` fields. But then where do I get the key and secret from? I know my region, but can't understand where to get the secret and key from. There's a key available for the SES user inside IAM, but it has no secret there. Just a key.

Do I need to use the AWS secret and key? This is really confusing, please help.

Comment: You need your AWS secret and key: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/get-aws-keys.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the secret and key. Look at [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSGettingStartedGuide/AWSCredentials.html) to see how to obtain these settings. If you've already done this and can't physically view the data anymore you'll probably need to delete the old key and regenerate a new one so you can see it.

You *may* need to supply `MAIL_USERNAME`. I'm not 100% on needing `MAIL_PASSWORD`, probably not though.

Comment: Okay. And if I use SMTP, do I put the driver as `smtp` or as `ses` ?

Comment: `ses`. The package internals will tell mail to use SES's SMTP driver.

Comment: @omrakhur are you using a composer package in Laravel for this? You didn't specify. Probably `aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel` if anything right?

Comment: I have copied the aws root key and secret into my `config/aws.php` as well as into `config/servies.php`, is that the right way to go?

Comment: It's up to you to define your convention. Personally I like to stick all my environmental variables that might change across testing/production environments inside the `.env` file and just make sure you update all references in the config files to pull from the `.env` file. If there are settings that will never change per environment it's best to keep them in the `config/services.php` config. Technically you really don't need to use environmental variables at all here, you could stick all your settings in the `/config` files.